# Trying to access nested function, "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, protractor, pageobjects

I'm working on some end-to-end tests using JavaScript (Protractor). I've got a PageObjects file that contains the following:

```
var SomeClass = function() {
    this.get = function() {
        browser.get('http://blah');
    };

    this.person = function() {
        var firstNameInput = element(by.id('firstName'));
        var lastNameInput = element(by.id('lastName'));

        this.setTitle = function(title) {
            element(by.xpath('//select[@id="title"]/option[text()="' + title +'"]')).click();
        };

        this.setFirstName = function(firstName) {
            firstNameInput.sendKeys(firstName);
        };

        this.setLastName = function(lastName) {
            lastNameInput.sendKeys(lastName);
        };
    };
};

module.exports = new SomeClass();
```

In my spec, I'm trying to access the nested function like this:

```
describe('some test', function() {
    var someClass = require('./some_class.po.js');
    var data = require('./some_class.data.json');

    it('do stuff', function() {
        someClass.get();
        someClass.person.setTitle(data.title);
        someClass.person.setFirstName(data.firstName);
        someClass.person.setLastName(data.lastName);
    });
});
```

When I try to run this test, the higher level `someClass.get()` works just fine, but when it attempts to execute `someClass.person.setTitle(data.title)`, I get a `Failed: undefined is not a function` message.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm only using setters, no getters. Don't think I need to return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make some changes in your code to access `inner` functions of `person()`. Added `return this` at the end of `person()`, so that the inner properties and methods of `person()` can be accessed from outside of the `person()`.

See the changes highlighted in the code below.

```js
var SomeClass = function() {
  this.get = function() {
    browser.get('http://blah');
  };

  this.person = function() {
    var firstNameInput = element(by.id('firstName'));
    var lastNameInput = element(by.id('lastName'));

    this.setTitle = function(title) {
      element(by.xpath('//select[@id="title"]/option[text()="' + title + '"]')).click();
    };

    this.setFirstName = function(firstName) {
      firstNameInput.sendKeys(firstName);
    };

    this.setLastName = function(lastName) {
      lastNameInput.sendKeys(lastName);
    };

    return this;
    // ^^^^^^^^^
  };
};

module.exports = new SomeClass();
```

Then, you can access `setTitle` as follow.

```
someClass.person().setTitle(data.title)
//              ^^
```

**Demo**

```js
var SomeClass = function() {
  this.person = function() {
    this.setTitle = function(title) {
      document.write(title);
    };

    return this;
    // ^^^^^^^^^
  };
};

var myObj = new SomeClass();
myObj.person().setTitle('Hello World!');
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to work because `person()` doesn't return anything and you're not calling `new someClass.person()`